# Rotation animation is clipped when using Hardware or Software layer

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-animation, android-cardview

```
ViewCompat.setPivotY(itemView, 0);    
ViewCompat.setRotationX(itemView, -80F);
ViewCompat.animate(itemView)
                .rotationX(0)
                .setDuration(450)
                .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
```

itemView is `CardView`
The right edge of the itemView is clipped, when using hardware or software layer. It works fine with `NO_LAYER`.

The issues reproduces on android M[not checked on others], both on device and emulator.

My app needs to support API 15+.

How can I fix this issue?